# selecting fetched data from dropdown and then submitting it to database

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

Sorry for the confusing title; I've got a small HTML form

```
<form action="somefile.php" method = "POST">
```

which contains two dropdowns, both of which contain the same data (an array of football teams) which is fetched from my MySQL database.

The thing is, for some reason, I am able to fetch the data and select it in the dropdown, but the data I select gets treated as null-values and therefore isn't sent off (I check for this in another PHP file).

The syntax is super basic, but I can't seem to wrap my head around the problem...

I first populate an array with the fetched data from the database:

```
$teams = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response)) {
array_push($teams, $row['team_name']);
```

I then unload this data into two `<select>` html elements separately (only one pictured below)

```
echo '<p>Home Team: <select name="home_team" value ="">';
foreach ($teams as $team) {
echo '<option value="">' . $team . '</option>';
}
```

Once the form is submitted, I do all the usual null-value checking in another file and that's as far as it gets; the data isn't sent off because my`$data_missing` array variable actually contains the two attributes previously selected in the dropdowns i.e. both of them were inserted as null-values even though I had selected two teams from the two dropdowns and submitted the form

P.S. using MySQL 10.4.14 flimsily connected to the XAMPP 3.2.4 using Apache 2.4 and PHP 7.2.34

Comment: `<select>` doesn't have a `value` attribute. In your `<option>`s though, every `value` attribute is empty. Either add a value or remove `value=""` completely to use the `<option>`'s text as value

Comment: @brombeer wow that's embarassing, thanks so much for taking the time to spot the mitsake, I'll mark this as solved